# Magento 2.0 with upgraded to php 7.0 Indexer Stuck at processing

Tags: php, magento2, indexer, apache2, php-7

With Apache2.4 mariaDB php7.0.2 everything working correctly with php7 extensions except for my products dont display when searched in magento2 Front-end. After checking for anything that could have changed I updated my Cron jobs to

```
*/1 * * * * php -c /etc/php/7.0/cli/apache2 /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run
*/1 * * * * php -c /etc/php/7.0/cli/apache2 /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php
*/1 * * * * php -c /etc/php/7.0/cli/apache2 /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run
*/1 * * * * php -c /etc/php/7.0/cli/apache2 /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Each command runs perfectly manually But when i go to the Admin-Backend this is what I get in the Index section.
[image: Indexer processing]

After searching for anyone else I seen on here that @[Alex Paliarush](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/697/alex-paliarush) said you have to run this command to fix stuck at processing.

```
 update magento.indexer_state set status='invalid' where status ='working'
```

So i ran this command in SQL via phpmyadmin the sql was successful but it fixed half the problem the Catalog search is still processing. so I stopped cron jobs and ran the sql query again then manually ran Indexer:reindex and got this error.

```
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So this Fixed my Customer Grid indexer and left me with this.
[image: Magento2 Indexer Catalog Search]

I believe because the indexer isn't correctly indexing my products its causing them to not show up on the frontend of the site i didn't have this problem on php5.6

I enabled php7.0-cli log to find the error when running indexer here's what i have gotten.

```
[10-Jan-2016 11:19:36 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 140022063078552 bytes) in /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/AbstractModel.php on line 442
```

So some how there is a bug thgats trying to use over 140 terabytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@acidreian PHP7 issues have been fixed in [tag 2.0.1](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.0.1) Please try and let us know if your issue has been fixed.

Comment: So after having issues upgrading to 2.0.1 then finally getting it to work by using my fix I have posted in [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98521/magento-ce-2-0-0-upgrade-to-magento-ce-2-0-1-fails-to-update-with-no-errors?noredirect=1#comment133386_98521) Then updating to back to php 7.0.2. Then I updated to 2.0.2 using My fix in composer once again (with the php7 patch already applied) because system Upgrade is a joke. I have a fully functional apache2.4 php7.0.2 Magento 2.0.2 working. No problems as of yet its only been 1 day though.

Answer (score 0):

Thats seems to be just SQL code. You can run it from the commandline when you log into your database. Or you could run it from a webtool like phpmyadmin if you are using mySQL.

Comment: So i updated my results and still having the problem.

Comment: Segmentation fault means: 1. Very basically, it means your program is trying to access a memory area it is not suposed to. 2. To the current directoy. 3. You need to make sure your program doesn't do 1.. From following topic. See for more details: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2071988

Comment: added Php7.0-cli log with the error output for the SegFault.

Comment: 140 terabytes? I see 1073741824 bytes. What is the memory limit now? Did you try to increase it yet?

Comment: my memory limit is 1024M, 1073741824 bytes = 1.07 GB. 140022063078552 bytes is how much memory the AbstractModel.php on line 442 tried to allocate which is = 140.02 Terabytes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is problem in php7.0.x with `yield` operator. In some specific case it will SegFault (like in Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Action/Full.php:378).

Comment: So should this be submmited as core problem with php7.0.x?