# Magento CE 2.0.0 upgrade to Magento CE 2.0.1 Fails to update with no errors

Tags: magento2, upgrade

After Getting the System Upgrade to Complete a Readiness Check and Complete the Full backup the Update process begins after 5 minutes some lines are displayed in the Console log.

```
[2016-01-22 10:44:07 UTC] Job "maintenance_mode {"enable":true}" has been started
[2016-01-22 10:44:07 UTC] Magento maintenance mode is enabled.
[2016-01-22 10:44:07 UTC] Job "maintenance_mode {"enable":true}" has successfully completed
[2016-01-22 10:44:07 UTC] Job "update {"components":[{"name":"magento/product-community-edition","version":"2.0.1"}]}" has been started
[2016-01-22 10:44:07 UTC] Starting composer update...
```

After sitting for an almost 2 hours with only this being displayed in the Console Log I'm clueless to know what happen because Google Inspect/Network displays that

Status

```
{,…}
complete: false
error: false
isUpdateInProgress: true
pending: false
```

Ideas?
[image: Status of magento2 upgrade]

After 11.4 hours of wating and the status being updating saying no errors the installation finally completed saying it has stopped due to error then says try to roll the system back. or click here to manually roll the system back.
This is my var/update_status.log

```
[2016-01-22 10:44:07 UTC] Job "maintenance_mode {"enable":true}" has been started
[2016-01-22 10:44:07 UTC] Magento maintenance mode is enabled.
[2016-01-22 10:44:07 UTC] Job "maintenance_mode {"enable":true}" has successfully completed
[2016-01-22 10:44:07 UTC] Job "update {"components":   {"name":"magento/product-community-edition","version":"2.0.1"}]}" has     been started
[2016-01-22 10:44:07 UTC] Starting composer update...
[2016-01-22 10:44:07 UTC] ./composer.json has been updated
```

[image]

Then I tried clicking the Rollback button which run no code just greyed the box out. 
So then i proceeded to do the manual rollback using magento.docs
rolled back media and code successfully then must have error-ed out while doing DB rollback because then the file bin/magento Poof diapered.
[image]

Comment: If you installed 2.0 via packagist, there is an issue with 2.0.1. Please add repo.magento.com to your composer.json, and related auth info in the auth.json file. Also, please check `var/update_status.log` file. anything in there?

Comment: looks like its my turn to stare at "System Upgrade Status: Update pending".
.. desperately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a Solution although its not exactly How i wanted to be able to Update Magento 2.0.0 to 2.0.1 because so far for me Magento2 is full of bugs and problems. but so far on 2.0.1 its been just as stable as 2.0.0 has been.

Solution to my problem was to start over because I'm using Google.cloud I had a snapshot before trying to upgrade to 2.0.1 because i knew there was gonna be problems.

So those of you who run into this problem like me & are using a Fresh CE 2.0.0 Installation Do this to Upgrade to Magento CE 2.0.1 via Composer CLI.

Step 1
open a SSH terminal navigate to Magento install directory.
mine was.

```
/var/www/html/magento2

sudo php bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

Step 2

```
Edit /var/www/html/magento2/Composer.json in mage Dir.
sudo nano composer.json
Find line change 2.0.0 to 2.0.1 Example below
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.0.1",
```

Step 3

```
Execute these one by one.
touch vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/js/JsTestDriver/.gitignore
touch vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/api-functional/.gitignore
touch vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/unit/.gitignore
touch vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/static/.gitignore
touch vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/.gitignore
touch vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/functional/.gitignore
mkdir dev/tests/integration/tmp
```

Step 4

```
Run
composer self-update
composer update
You will see composer do this towards the end.
  - Removing magento/magento2-base (2.0.0)
  - Installing magento/magento2-base (2.0.1)
    Downloading: 100%
```

Step 5

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo php bin/magento maintenance:disable
Optional:
sudo php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Step 6

```
2.0.1 Should be successfully installed but permissions might me screwed up.
so re-apply permissions. something like this.
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento2
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;
sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
sudo find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
sudo find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
sudo find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
sudo chmod 777 ./app/etc
sudo chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```

Permissions might Very Depending on how your using your magento2 installation.
Thanks to @[Rob Mangiafico](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/2831/rob-mangiafico) for his help on another Stackexchange question.